# strncmp not working in ObjectARX 2018

Tags: c, objectarx

In an ObjectARX 2018 Project we have a .c file containing the below code :

```
while(fgetws((wchar_t *)line, 80, fp) != NULL) {
if((!strncmp((const char*)line, "REQ",3)) || (!strncmp((const char*)line, 
"ROL",3)) ||
      (!strncmp((const char*)line, "NLS",3)) || (!strncmp((const char*)line, 
"NDW",3))) {
        //Inside If
      }
      //Outside if
}
```

This while loop is reading a file with the below data :

ACAD3|14789536|005|MISC BULK CA & WIRE, CA RK, AUX FR & LTG

REQ|G3060901|1|

REQ|G3060906|1|

REQ|G3060907|1|

REQ|G3062062|4|

REQ|G3062095|1|

we need to enter into if only if line starts with REQ, ROL, NLS, NDW. But we are not able to.

This was working in ObjectARX 2014.

Can anybody tell us how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you really cast a Wide Char to a Char like that?

Comment: I am new to C/C++. Sorry I don't know. Could you guide me how to cast wchar_t to char. I will also look into it.

Comment: You can't cast wchar to char.  wchar is (usually) a 16 bit character code where as char is an 8 bit code.  Either use `fgets()` to get a char in the first place or use `wcscmp()` to compare wide strings.  If its for Windows you could look at the `CA2W` class.

Comment: @AbhilashDK just casting it won't help, you'd need some conversion function and in general, this will lose information: the point of `wchar_t` is to support encodings with **more** code points than would fit into a byte.

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t` is **most** likely something completely different than `char` and casting a pointer only silences the compiler. If you're dealing with wide chars, there are functions for that, e.g. [`wcscmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wcscmp) and friends:

```
 wchar_t *line;
 [...]
 if ((!wcsncmp(line, L"REQ", 3))
```

Comment: Hi I tried this if ((!wcsncmp(line, L"REQ", 3)) || (!wcsncmp(line, L"ROL", 3)) ||
     (!wcsncmp(line, L"NLS", 3)) || (!wcsncmp(line, L"NDW", 3))) { But due to my warning level in Visual Studio I was getting error. I changed the Warning Level. Now it's working thanks.